# How correctly choose number of jobs for estimator and validation?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, parallel-processing, boosting

I have classification problem to solve and use different classificators to solve the task. I use `cross_val_score` and `cross_val_predict` for validation and prediction. Both of them and estimator, e.g. `LGBMClassifier` support parallelizing. I have 46 physical cores, each of which has 2 logical cores, so 92 total. How should I set up `n_jobs` parameter in all functions to achieve best perfomance?

```py
from lightgbm import LGBMClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, cross_val_predict

# X, y = predefined data
model = LGBMClassifier(n_estimators = 100, tree_learner='feature', n_jobs = ???)

score = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=5, n_jobs = ???)
```

My guess is that `n_jobs` of estimator should depend on parallelization technique, e.g. for `feature` case it should be equal to feature number. And as for validation, it probably should depend on number of folds. But it is only a guess. Is there sertified answer?